# Operating system tuning for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, tuning

I'm working at the pgconfig.org[1] tool. PgConfig it's a tool for suggest a tuning configuration for a PostgreSQL environment.

I'm finding some disk tuning documentations to implement a suggestion for operating system tuning. Any tips which parameters are important?

References:

1. http://pgconfig.org

Comment: Go look around in the PostgreSQL Wiki.

Comment: it might help. http://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/ and you could refer postgres documentation (postgres official website) for specific parameter and usage.

Comment: my project do the same thing @Spike. I will take a look at the doc looking for more parameters.

Comment: @dezso do you mention that https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization?

Comment: Yes, exactly that one.

Comment: thanks @dezso. i will see that. Any moe ideas are welcome. :)